# Creating a looping batch file with command line parameters?

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, arguments

I've got a command line program that edits single files to add a time length to them. You enter the name of the program into the command prompt and then the file. So like this: "test.exe file.dsf". I'm trying to make a .bat file that will loop through all of the ".dsf" files in the folder. I tried this, but it just seems to run the program for each dsf file, but it doesn't enter it as a parameter after.

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO BATCH test


FOR %%a IN (*.dsf) DO test.exe
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Add the %%a as parameter to test.exe

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO BATCH test
FOR %%a IN (*.dsf) DO test.exe %%a
```

Comment: That was really quick and really easy. I feel a bit stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: @Turbohog: Perhaps you'll want to add double quotes around `%%a` (as the argument) to be safe against possible spaces or other special characters in file names. I mean like this: `FOR %%a IN (*.dsf) DO test.exe "%%a"`.